# Multiple errors when running a glmer for large number of fixed-effect predictors

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am running a glmer from package lme4 to predict the binary outcome an_larv_bin from a large number of predictor variables. The predictor variables are mostly numerical, and 3 are factors.

This is what I run:

```
point3 <- glmer(an_larv_bin ~  month + TRMM_20150 + EVI + NDVI + houseDist + DEM + Euc_Recent + Built_Euc + Acacia_Euc + Water_Euc + Intact_For + Clearing_E + Bush_Euc_D + Rice_Euc_D + Palm_Euc_D + Mix_Euc_Di + Rubber_Euc + Aspect_Map + Slope_Map + TWI_Map + density_v + diversity + (1|water_body_id), family="binomial", data=points3)
```

I come up against the following warning message when I run the model:

```
 Warning messages:
1: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling 
2: In (function (fn, par, lower = rep.int(-Inf, n), upper = rep.int(Inf,  :
  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
4: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues
```

And when I run:

```
summary(point3)
```

I get the following warning messages:

```
    Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 44 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it

fit warnings:
Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
convergence code: 0
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 3 negative eigenvalues
failure to converge in 10000 evaluations

Warning messages:
1: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
2: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
```

I have rescaled all variables and came up against the same warnings.

Here is the data I am working with

```
> dput(points3[1:5, c(1, 3, 13, 26, 48:68)])
structure(list(samp_id = c(274L, 1L, 275L, 276L, 2L), month = c("may", 
"may", "may", "may", "may"), water_body_id = c("4937_PO1", "3270_IS1", 
"2854_IS1", "3270_IS2", "2582_RV1"), an_larv_bin = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L), TRMM_20150 = c(0.107319515, 0.049805214, 0.049805214, 
0.049805214, 0.118292061), EVI = c(0.499929994, 0.589900017, 
0.593994021, 0.589900017, 0.601158023), NDVI = c(0.691016972, 
0.798900008, 0.782992005, 0.798900008, 0.772291005), houseDist = c(364.0050049, 
50.99020004, 67.08200073, 50.99020004, 67.08200073), DEM = c(31L, 
24L, 26L, 24L, 26L), Euc_Recent = c(30, 84.85279846, 84.85279846, 
84.85279846, 84.85279846), Built_Euc = c(150.0070038, 60.00289917, 
60.00289917, 60.00289917, 60.00289917), Acacia_Euc = c(23827.69922, 
21825, 21825, 21825, 21825), Water_Euc = c(1213.47998, 201.2559967, 
201.2559967, 201.2559967, 201.2559967), Intact_For = c(18160.40039, 
18621.69922, 18621.69922, 18621.69922, 18621.69922), Clearing_E = c(0, 
67.08529663, 67.08529663, 67.08529663, 67.08529663), Bush_Euc_D = c(523.9530029, 
305.9559937, 305.9559937, 305.9559937, 305.9559937), Rice_Euc_D = c(174.9369965, 
390.0190125, 390.0190125, 390.0190125, 390.0190125), Palm_Euc_D = c(218.4140015, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Mix_Euc_Di = c(192.1029968, 30.00139999, 30.00139999, 
30.00139999, 30.00139999), Rubber_Euc = c(84.85690308, 212.1419983, 
212.1419983, 212.1419983, 212.1419983), Aspect_Map = c(189.1159973, 
163.423996, 163.423996, 163.423996, 163.423996), Slope_Map = c(13.28279972, 
5.421599865, 5.421599865, 5.421599865, 5.421599865), TWI_Map = c(4.844860077, 
5.756090164, 5.756090164, 5.756090164, 5.756090164), density_v = c("sparse", 
"planted", "dense", "dense", "sparse"), diversity = c("bush", 
"monoculture", "farmed_mixed", "farmed_mixed", "mixed_forest"
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Is that the entirety of your data or just the first five rows? If the latter, how much data do you have? Your model is really complex. Maybe it would be helpful to start with a smaller numer of predictors and build it up step by step. This way you would also recognize if any specific predictor causes problems.

Comment: Hi benimwolfspelz. That is just the first five rows. There are 368 obs for each variable.

Comment: If I'm counting it correctly, you have 23 predictors and only 368 observations? This is a pretty low amount of observations for a logistic regression. With that many predictors, it's pretty likely that you are running into a case of complete separation, which will break the model in a variety of ways.